# Android: RelativeLayout inside FrameLayout, width height bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

What I have:

`activity_comics.xml` - layout container for two fragments: list of comicses (view_comicses.xml) and detail comics view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/comics_fragment_container">
</FrameLayout>
```

`view_comicses.xml` - fragment with staggered listview

```
<com.agimind.widget.huewu.pla.lib.MultiColumnListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pla="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/multicollist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    pla:plaColumnNumber="2"
    pla:plaLandscapeColumnNumber="3">
</com.agimind.widget.huewu.pla.lib.MultiColumnListView>
```

`view_comics_detail.xml` - fragment for detail view of comics

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comics_image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After `view_comicses.xml` and `view_comics_detail.xml` fragments added to `activity_comics.xml`, resulting layout should be like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/comics_fragment_container">

    <com.agimind.widget.huewu.pla.lib.MultiColumnListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:pla="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/multicollist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        pla:plaColumnNumber="2"
        pla:plaLandscapeColumnNumber="3">
    </com.agimind.widget.huewu.pla.lib.MultiColumnListView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comics_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

But for some reasons resulting layout look like this

[image: resulting layout]

width and height of `RelativeLayout` are equals match_parent, but on render as if equal wrap_content. Why is this happening? I tried difference params for `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, but not work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The RelativeLayout is trying to match the FrameLayout's width but can't because the MultiColumnListView being there. The FrameLayout then splits it's available space to both children.

If you want both the RelativeLayout and the MultiColumnListView to have the same width as the FrameLayout (and overlap), you'll need to change the FrameLayout to a RelativeLayout.

FrameLayout is more often used to display a single child. It's possible to add multiple children but then you need to specify the android:layout_gravity for each children to control their positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color of your RelativeLayout. Can you see it behind your images? Your RelativeLayout matches parent but your ImageView wraps content. Are your images the correct size to fill the screen?